# Submitting an array index through form without input in php

Tags: php

SOLVED

I am trying to submit the value of `$data['saleId']` to the info.php page.

```
       echo "<form action='info.php' method='post'>
       <input type='hidden' name='saleId' value='$data['saleId']'>
       <input type='submit' value='View Info'>
       </form>";
```

gives

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or
>   number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Can you share php code please?

Comment: `$data['saleId']` should be `{$data['saleId']}` when using arrays in `"` enclosed strings.

Answer (score 1):

The string formed is incorrect.

Using string concatenation:

```
echo "<form action='info.php' method='post'>
       <input type='hidden' name='saleId' value=\'".$data['saleId']."\'>
       <input type='submit' value='View Info'>
       </form>";
```

Using HereDoc:

```
echo <<<EOD
 <form action='info.php' method='post'>
       <input type='hidden' name='saleId' value='{$data['saleId']}'>
       <input type='submit' value='View Info'>
 </form>
EOD;
```

> Note `EOD;` should always be at the start of the line.

Please refer: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: "$data['saleId'] should be {$data['saleId']} when using arrays in " enclosed strings. – kerbholz "

Comment: @user2892730, not necessary with string concatenation.